In what way is idolatry the end of evils, as per Wisdom 14:27?
We read in Wisdom of Solomon 14:27 (RSV):

For the worship of idols not to be named
is the beginning and cause and end of every evil.

One  can easily comprehend the concept that idolatry is the beginning and cause of every evil. But, what about its being the end of evils ? How do Bible scholars explain the concept ?

We should think of "end" here in the sense of goal (as in means vs. ends) rather than a termination point. The thought is that idolatry is the alpha and omega of evil, not that evil is eliminated in idolatry. The text tells us that evil begins with worshiping false gods and sacrificing children to them; it finds its conclusion in the creation of a completely disordered world.  This translation in context may help in understanding:

While they practice either child sacrifices or occult mysteries,
or frenzied carousing in exotic rites,
24 they no longer respect either lives or purity of marriage;
but they either waylay and kill each other, or aggrieve each other by adultery.25 And all is confusion—blood and murder, theft and guile,
corruption, faithlessness, turmoil, perjury, 26 disturbance of good people, neglect of gratitude,
besmirching of souls, unnatural lust,
disorder in marriage, adultery and shamelessness. 27 For the worship of infamous idols
is the reason and source and extreme [end] of all evil. (NABRE)

Conclusion: The text teaches that, through idolatry and its derivatives, every form of evil emerges. The purpose of these evils is to create a world of moral confusion, a chaos much worse that the primordial void from which God created order. Thus, the "end" of evil is not evil's elimination but a perverse universe, absolutely opposite to the good things intended by God.

St. Jerome says something interesting,

In a general way all that is of the devil savors of enmity to God, and
what is of the devil is idolatry, since all idols are subject to him. (Page 15) 1


I do not deny that all of us who believe in Christ have passed from
the error of idolatry. For we are' not born Christians, but become
Christians by being born again. And because we formerly worshipped
idols, does it follow that we ought not now to worship God lest we
seem to pay like honour to Him and to idols? (Page 420) 1

Idolatry as the “beginning” of every evil is placing anything or anyone above God. Or as it has been stated before:

Idolatry is the usurpation of divine authority. The image of the idol
represents disobedience. This image stems from original disobedience
in the Garden of Eden. 2

It was expressed in the 10 commandments as such: Exodus 20:3-4

3 “You shall have no other gods before me.
4 “You shall not make for yourself a carved image, or any likeness of
anything that is in heaven above, or that is in the earth beneath, or
that is in the water under the earth.

It is this same idolatry that leads to the final judgment for, as St. Jerome stated, all idolatry is of the devil. It leads to the ultimate ruin of an individual. It is the culmination of evil. It includes all that is turning away from God; the rejection of truth and righteousness.
Take 2 Kings 17:15-18 for example.

15 They despised his statutes and his covenant that he made with their
fathers and the warnings that he gave them. They went after false
idols and became false, and they followed the nations that were around
them, concerning whom the Lord had commanded them that they should not
do like them. 16 And they abandoned all the commandments of the Lord
their God, and made for themselves metal images of two calves; and
they made an Asherah and worshiped all the host of heaven and served
Baal. 17 And they burned their sons and their daughters as
offerings and used divination and omens and sold themselves to do
evil in the sight of the Lord, provoking him to anger. 18 Therefore
the Lord was very angry with Israel and removed them out of his sight.
None was left but the tribe of Judah only.

What was the consequences of idolatry? The end product? They were removed from the Lord's sight.
So I see this idolatry as the "end of every evil" as 2 things:

It is the beginning and end = total and ultimate rejection of God
It concludes with judgment and separation from God.





References




1
Schaff, Philip, and Henry Wace. A Select Library of Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers of the Christian Church: St. Jerome: Letters and Select Works, 1893. 1893.


2
Joseph. “What Does the Word “Idols” Mean in 1 John 5:21 and What Exactly Is Idolatry?” Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange, 4 Nov. 2013, hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/9265/58339. Accessed 4 Dec. 2024.



